# Can a network failure cause a user to be removed from SQL as an authorized user?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We are trying to get to the bottom of our issue.  We have a service that connects as MyDomain\ServiceAdmin to a SQL 2008 database.

I believe we have just setup database mirroring too in case the DB/network goes down and we lose connectivity, but we most likely have not tested it.

We had various network issues and then maybe 30+ min later, the service failed and could not connect, saying "Login failed for MyDomain\ServiceAdmin" in the event viewer.

I connect to SQL and the server is running, the DB is there, but the user is not there under (DB>Security>Users) in SQL.  Our DBA re-adds the user, and everything works.

DBA is pointing to network issues causing the problem and the user missing.  Is that possible or are the network issues just a coincidence and he's trying to CYA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DBA is pointing to network issues causing the problem and the user missing. Is that possible or are the network issues **just a coincidence and he's trying to CYA**?

I believe you have your answer.

Comment: Is there any way the mirroring had something to do with it?  If perhaps they mirroring wasn't setup correctly?

Comment: Even if database mirroring is set up, it wouldn't randomly delete a single user unless that user was deleted in the first place on one of the mirrors.

Comment: I'm being told that somehow the network failed and the SQL didn't see that account as existing anymore and automatically removed it from the database as an authorized user.  Is that a load of smoke?

Comment: I feel like it is just smoke. There is nothing in MSSQL that should do this. I suppose there could be some custom routine that the DBA coded in, but it's doubtful. If this was the case, all other users from MyDomain should be gone as well.